# Can't update Git repo

Tags: git

```
Adam@Aderm MINGW64 ~/code/Test Server (master)  
$ git commit  
On branch master  
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.  
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   .classpath
    modified:   bin/aderm/pw/testserver/Listeners/Join.class
    modified:   bin/aderm/pw/testserver/Main.class
    modified:   plugin.yml
    modified:   src/aderm/pw/testserver/Listeners/Join.java
    modified:   src/aderm/pw/testserver/Main.java

Untracked files:
    bin/aderm/pw/testserver/Commands/Heal.class
    bin/aderm/pw/testserver/Commands/Ping.class
    bin/aderm/pw/testserver/Listeners/BlockStuff.class
    bin/aderm/pw/testserver/Utils/
    src/aderm/pw/testserver/Commands/Heal.java
    src/aderm/pw/testserver/Commands/Ping.java
    src/aderm/pw/testserver/Listeners/BlockStuff.java
    src/aderm/pw/testserver/Utils/

no changes added to commit
```

Yet I've added code/folders to the src file.

When I try `git push -u origin master`:

```
Adam@Aderm MINGW64 ~/code/Test Server (master)
$ git push -u origin master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Use `git add` to stage files which you want to commit.  You did not do this, hence nothing to push.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to git :)

Answer (score 0):

> Yet I've added code/folders to the src file.

You need to `git add` that folder first so that it's under git control

```
git add src
```

before `commit` and `push`

```
git commit -am "add src"
git push origin master
```